# Use Caps Lock to switch to and from languages on Sierra

Tags: keyboard, macos

Sierra added [this feature that allows you to switch from a to Latin layout from a non-Latin layout by Caps Lock](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25369?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). 
It doesn't work with Russian, although last time I checked Russian was a non-Latin language.

Does anyone have any luck with working around this bug?

Comment: I tested a number of them and it looks like Russian and Greek may be the only ones where this does not work.  Probably something Apple has to fix.

Comment: Oh :( The problem is [seil doesn't work anymore](https://github.com/tekezo/Seil/issues/68). So I am stuck :( Time to downgrade.

Comment: Did anyone send a bug report?

Comment: It doesn't work in Bulgarian (phonetic) layout also. There is no checkbox "Use the Caps Lock key to switch to and from Bulgarian".

Comment: @TomGewecke According to [this source](http://www.macworld.com/article/3123735/macs/how-to-use-cap-locks-in-macos-sierra-to-switch-between-keyboards-that-use-different-characters.html), Japanese isn't working, either (so likely Korean as well. I wonder if Chinese works or not). I didn't test it out as I'm on still El Capitan, though.

Comment: @Blaszard  Chinese and Korean do work.  Japanese is a special case, because the IM has an internal version of US, Romaji, which Japanese users normally access via a special key on a Japanese keyboard.  No excuse for leaving out all Cyrilllic and Greek keyboards however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My tests indicate that the Caps Lock switching feature now works with Cyrillic, Greek, and Armenian keyboards in High Sierra.  (These do not work in Sierra).

Comment: Alliluya! I can retire Karabiner!

Answer (score 6):

To switch keyboard layout with caps-lock key you need to
remap caps-lock to F18 with command (in Terminal.app):

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000039,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000006D}]}'
```

Then, go to System Preferences/Keyboard/Shortcuts/Input Sources, use key 'caps lock' to switch input source.

No additional software is required on mac os Sierra.

To keep this working after you logout do the following:
create file `~/bin/caps2f18.sh` with the following content:

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000039,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000006D}]}' > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/caps2f18.sh
```

Create file `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.user.loginscript.plist` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>Label</key>
   <string>com.user.loginscript</string>
   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
   <array>
        <string>zsh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>~/bin/caps2f18.sh</string>
   </array>
   <key>RunAtLoad</key>
   <true/>
   <key>ThrottleInterval</key>
   <integer>86400</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Execute

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.user.loginscript.plist
```

logout login, or execute `launchctl start com.user.loginscript`

Comment: After you this, does caps lock always switch keyboards, regardless of whether non-latin ones are involved?  Does it switch to the last keyboard used?  Or the next one on the list?

Comment: I have 2 - us and ua(non latin, cyryllic) keyboard layouts. This method is just mapping caps-lock to F18. Standard mac os input source switcher is not modified.

Comment: But it would also switch two latin keyboards, right?  What would it do with 3 keyboards?

Comment: yes and latin too, if you set "Select next source in input menu" to F18 (capslock) it will switch 3 keyboards one-by one.

Answer (score 4):

Although both Seil and the classic [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) don't work anymore under Sierra, Karabiner rewrite, ["Karabiner Elements"](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) (in a very early beta) actually works.

The UI key mapping doesn't yet work, but you can edit the config json file under `~/.karabiner.d/configuration/karabiner.json` (see an example below) to map Caps Lock to F19. From there it's all the same as before - disable Caps Lock, map keyboard layout triggering to F19, profit.

Example karabiner.json:

```
{  "profiles": [
    {
      "name": "Default profile",
      "selected": true,
      "simple_modifications": {
        "caps_lock": "f19"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Downgrade deferred!

Comment: How did you map the layout triggering to F19? Since Karabiner is not working anymore, it is not working, either, right?

Answer (score 0):

To extend JBaruch's answer, this is a configuration for Karabiner to send Ctrl+Option+Space when CapsLock is clicked. This will switch the keyboard layout immediately - without delay of showing the list of available layouts. Its required to have Ctrl+Option+Space configured as a system shortcut for switching a layout.

To install it, copy it as a .json file to
~/.config/karabiner/assets

```
{
  "title": "CapsLock to change language",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "CapsLock to Ctrl + Option + Space",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "from": {
              "key_code": "caps_lock"
          },
          "to_if_alone": [
              {
                  "key_code": "spacebar",
                  "modifiers": [
                    "left_control",
                    "left_option"
                  ]
              }
          ],
          "type": "basic"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```